# Connect IoT devices to AWS

Tags: raspberry-pi, networking, aws-iot, aws

I have a Moxa I/O Remote connected to a Raspberry Pi running some scripts through pymodbus. I am using MQTT to publish & receive changes/requests in the I/O remote to a web service.

The idea is to have the web service & I/O remote running in one location, and the RBP in another location. Therefore I need some kind of service from AWS to be able to connect these two, speaking to the same network to put it simply. I was thinking of using a VPN box for the I/O remote and Raspberry Pi, but I am unsure of which service in AWS that could help me achieve a software solution for this.

I have attached a screenshot of the hardware setup – now I am wondering which AWS service to use.

[image]

Comment: AWS is a toolbox, for VPN you probably need [AWS VPC VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html). If you're using MQTT already a look at AWS IoT might the next step. Not sure what your box in the middle is? The Linux system could be EC2 as well. Anyways some more information would get you better answers.

Comment: The box in the middle is just hardware stored at Location A. The I/O remote will also be stored at location A. I need some kind of service to connect Location A to Location B through set IP addresses, since I can't set them at the office network. So I assume the VPN setup would be the best option?